# Passing mutable context into callbacks

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to build a simple UI in Rust, but partly scriptable in Lua, using rust-lua53, and having problems working out a good way to give Lua components access to the Lua state.  This question/example is a little longer than I'd like, sorry!

The core of the UI is a `Widget` trait with methods to call when keys are pressed or when the screen/window should be redrawn.  The type parameter `C` is the context I'll want to pass in (see later).

```
trait Widget<C> {
    fn handle_key<'c>(&mut self, key: char, context: &'c mut C);
}
```

There's a `UI` struct which handles the event loop, reading keys and calling the `draw` method (left out for the question).  The `Widget` trait and `UI` runner are generic and can be used without anything Lua-related.

```
struct UI {}
impl UI {
    pub fn run<'c, 'm, T, C>(&mut self, widget: 'm T, context: &'c mut C)
        where C: 'c, T: Widget<C>
    {
    }
}
```

You use it by implementing `Widget` and calling `ui.run(widget)`, which runs an event loop until it's "finished" (say a button is pressed on the widget), and control is returned to the caller.

There's a wrapper around the Lua state, which (amongst other things) handles safely getting pointers to Rust objects out:

```
struct RL<'a> {
    marker: PhantomData<(&'a ())>,
}
impl<'a> RL<'a> {
        pub fn get<T>(&mut self) -> Option<Ptr<T>>
            where T: Any
        { unimplemented!() }
    pub fn register(&mut self, func: (&'static str, fn(&mut RL) -> ()))
    { unimplemented!() }

}
```

There's a smart pointer (which is just an `Rc<RefCell<T>>`) used with objects passed to Lua, so that Rust code can do mutable things even if there's a reference stashed away in the Lua state:

```
struct Ptr<T> {
    obj: Rc<RefCell<T>>,
}
impl<T> Clone for Ptr<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Ptr{ obj: self.obj.clone() }
    }
}

impl<T> Ptr<T> {
    pub fn borrow_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> RefMut<'a, T> where T:'a {
        (*self.obj).borrow_mut()
    }
}
```

And finally there's `MyWidget`, which is supposed to be a shim to allow Lua code to implement widgets, and this is where my current difficulty is.  The thinking is that:

- `MyWidget` does need (mutable) access to the Lua state, for example to be able to call Lua callbacks.
- `MyWidget` can't store a mutable reference to the Lua state, due to general `&mut` aliasing rules (it's obviously used in many other places).
- Therefore I need to pass the Lua state into `UI::run` and on to the `Widget` methods (hence adding the `C` parameter above).

```
struct MyWidget {}
struct MyContext<'a> {
    rl: &'a mut RL,  // mutable reference to the Lua state
}

impl<'b> Widget<MyContext<'b>> for MyWidget {
    fn handle_key(&mut self, key: char, context: &mut MyContext) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl MyWidget {
    // This static method is called from Lua, where `MyWidget` has been made available as a userdata.
    pub fn l_run(rl: &mut RL) {
        // First get a Rust pointer to the widget out of the Lua state
        let mut ui: Ptr<MyWidget> = rl.get().unwrap();

        // Create a fresh UI runner
        let mut rui = UI{};
        // Make the context including the Lua state
        let mut ctxt: MyContext = MyContext { rl: rl, };
        // Run the widget, passing the context.
        rui.run(&mut *ui.borrow_mut(), &mut ctxt);
    }
}
```

And finally, the l_run method needs to be registered:

```
fn main() {
    let mut rl = RL{marker: PhantomData};
    rl.register(("l_run", MyWidget::l_run));
}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=adbad0b15529bd90fb61a25d84a6235e&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The current attempt results in:

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
  --> <anon>:57:35
   |>
57 |>         let mut ctxt: MyContext = MyContext { rl: rl, };
   |>                                   ^^^^^^^^^
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn l_run<'a>(rl: &'a mut RL<'a>)
  --> <anon>:53:5
   |>
53 |>     pub fn l_run(rl: & mut RL) {
   |>     ^
```

But if I take the compiler's advice and add the explicit lifetime parameter, the function no longer matches the signature needed when registering, and I instead get:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
  --> <anon>:74:27
   |>
74 |>     rl.register(("l_run", MyWidget::l_run));
   |>                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter
note: expected type `fn(&mut RL<'_>)`
note:    found type `fn(&'r mut RL<'r>) {MyWidget::l_run}`
note: expected concrete lifetime is lifetime ReSkolemized(0, BrAnon(0))
```

So fixing the previous error means the signature is no longer compatible with the registration function (which isn't generic; in reality I pass in slices with several functions in one go).

Comment: That does seem to make the example build, thanks, but not the real code.  I guess I need to work out what's different.

Comment: I've edited to add the missing piece (registering the function) which stops that working in the actual application.

Comment: [Increase the number of lifetimes in `MyContext`?](http://127.0.0.1:5000/?gist=d5e4ea88772a0304f72a7d418fd2eedf)

Comment: Your link goes to localhost...

Comment: Sure, act like you don't have access to the most popular webpage on the Internet. [One more public](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=d5e4ea88772a0304f72a7d418fd2eedf) (note that the `gist` parameter works across both Playgrounds, I was just doing some local work on mine).

Comment: That seems to work (well, compile at least)), thank you!  Once I've fully absorbed both why it now works, and why it didn't before, I'll feel I have levelled up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These deep lifetime issues are hairy, so let's see if we can figure it out. Let's start with a look at a stripped-down version of the code that has the same error:

```
struct RunLoop<'a> {
    marker: &'a u8,
}

struct MyContext<'a> {
    rl: &'a mut RunLoop<'a>,
}

fn run(rl: &mut RunLoop) {
    let mut ctxt = MyContext { rl: rl };
}

fn main() {}
```

The definition of `MyContext` states that it needs to be provided a reference to a `RunLoop`. The lifetime of the `RunLoop` and the lifetime the `RunLoop` is parameterized with need to be unified - they are both set to `'a`. However, this cannot be guaranteed based on the signature of `run`. All that is known is that there are two lifetimes, both elided at the moment.

This leads to one solution: we can explicitly identify both lifetimes and establish a relationship between them:

```
struct MyContext<'a, 'b : 'a> {
    rl: &'a mut RunLoop<'b>,
}
```

Another solution is the one hinted at by the compiler: pre-unify the lifetimes when `run` has been called:

```
fn run<'a>(rl: &'a mut RunLoop<'a>) {
```

However, this latter solution doesn't work in the larger program, failing with:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
  --> src/main.rs:74:27
74 |>     rl.register(("l_run", MyWidget::l_run));
   |>                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter
note: expected type `fn(&mut RL<'_>)`
note:    found type `fn(&'a mut RL<'a>) {MyWidget::l_run}`
note: expected concrete lifetime is lifetime ReSkolemized(0, BrAnon(0))
```

(Side note: it's been a *long* time since I've seen a `ReSkolemized` mention in an error message!)

Let's extend our small example to generate the same error:

```
struct RunLoop<'a> {
    marker: &'a u8,
}

struct MyContext<'a> {
    rl: &'a mut RunLoop<'a>,
}

fn run<'a>(rl: &'a mut RunLoop<'a>) {
    let mut ctxt = MyContext { rl: rl };
}

fn register(func: fn(&mut RunLoop)) {}

fn main() {
    register(run);
}
```

This I'm less sure about. I do know that putting just about any explicit lifetime on the reference helps it compile:

```
fn register<'a>(func: fn(&'a mut RunLoop<'a>)) {}
fn register<'a, 'b>(func: fn(&'a mut RunLoop<'b>)) {}
fn register(func: fn(&'static mut RunLoop)) {}
```